# Generate c-style header from Font using Imagemagick

Tags: c, fonts, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I need to batch create font data for my graphical library. Since now, I successfully generate pixel data from Font using imagemagick, parsing different xbm files. I am using this command:

```
convert -resize 8x8\! -font FONT +dither label:A A.xbm
```

Imagemagick correctly generates the output file, but the image is not clear, like if there is some kind of noise or artifacts.

I would like to obtain a result comparable to mikroelektronika's GLCD Font Creator.

Maybe someone knows the correct command to send to imagemagick and solve this behaviour

Here I report two images: the one from imagemagick command (with the additional '-colors 2' parameter and the one that I would like to obtain

[image: Image generated by imagemagick]

[image: how the image should look like]

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do here, but try changing the command to `convert -font FONT +dither label:A -resize 8x8\! a.xbm` or maybe changing `-resize` to `-scale` and see if that helps.

Comment: I tried with both, neither of them solved my issue. The image has still a degree of blur on the edge. This blur causes a sub-optimal conversion to xbm format. I also tried with '+antialias' with no improvement

Comment: Can you enlarge and post your resulting image please?

Comment: Before I try to answer your question, can you explain **why** you "need to batch create font data for my graphical library" instead of just... you know... use OpenType fonts by using FreeType2, like everyone else?

Comment: because I'm programming on cortex-m core and I don't have unix support, so I need to generate a c header with the parsed font in order to use them.

Comment: But why with ImageMagick? What about converting font to 1bpp texture atlas with online bitmap font generator like http://kvazars.com/littera/ or desktop tool https://github.com/andryblack/fontbuilder (there's lot of them)?